# How to use colors/colorschemes/fonts in vim effectively so that the text is as readable as possible

Tags: linux, vim, osx, editors, vimrc

I am trying to be more productive in `vim` and as part of this I am trying to make the text presentation i.e. colors etc as nice to the eyesight as possible.
Although I managed to change the default color and cursorline and cursor colors etc, the colors I added where somewhat "random". I.e. what ever I found online. But the result is really not so good and readable.
Do you have a nice template about coloring in vim that I could use to make my life easier and text more readable?
As a side note I am using MacBook which has some transparency in the commandline and this also affects what the appearence is.
Also I am using vim for coding and not regular text editing if this makes a difference.

Comment: Do a search for Solarized. Your terminal transparency is configurable so you can remove it if it makes things easier.

Comment: @MelBoyce:Solarized?Is this something `vim` specific or mac specific?

Comment: Why don't you search for it and then you'll know? It's a color scheme designed for readability; there are configs for many applications.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of great Vim colorschemes with screenshots: http://www.vimninjas.com/2012/08/26/10-vim-color-schemes-you-need-to-own/

I personally prefer Monokai: https://github.com/tomasr/molokai

Also, whichever theme you choose, remember to make the font size bigger. I use 17 points.

Comment: Do you know what font is being used on this site?